# make4ht-lib: Fatal error

Tags: tex4ht

At some point in the past week or so, `tex4ht` seems to have stopped working on my computer. I now get this error when I run it while trying to convert from tex to odt:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?    Emergency stop.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
Error: source file could not be loaded
```

The bash command that generated this error was:

```bash
make4ht -ux -f odt  -c $configfile $filename.out.tex
```

where `$configfile` is `myconfig.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,ooffice}
\ConfigureOO{Footnote}{
<style:style
    style:name="Footnote"
    style:family="paragraph"
    style:parent-style-name="Standard"
    style:class="extra">\Hnewline
  <style:paragraph-properties
             fo:margin-left="0in"
             fo:margin-right="0in"
             fo:text-indent="0.1in"
              style:auto-text-indent="false"/>
  <style:text-properties fo:font-size="83.3333333333333333333333\%"
      style:font-size-asian="83.3333333333333333333333\%"
      style:font-size-complex="83.3333333333333333333333\%" />
</style:style>\Hnewline
<text:notes-configuration text:note-class="footnote"
    text:citation-style-name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
    text:citation-body-style-name="Footnote_20_anchor"
    style:num-format="1" text:start-value="0"
    text:footnotes-position="page"
    text:start-numbering-at="document" />\Hnewline
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
style:display-name="Footnote Symbol" style:family="text" >\Hnewline
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_anchor"
style:display-name="Footnote anchor" style:family="text">
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>\Hnewline
}

\ConfigureOO{verse}{\Hnewline
<style:style style:name="verse"
             style:family="paragraph"
             style:parent-style-name="Text-body"
             style:next-style-name="Text-body">
<style:paragraph-properties  fo:margin-left="1.499cm"
             fo:margin-right="1cm"
             fo:margin-top="0cm"
             fo:margin-bottom="0cm"
             fo:text-indent="-0.499cm"
             style:auto-text-indent="false">
   <style:tab-stops/>
</style:paragraph-properties >
</style:style>
\Hnewline}

\def\loopoverdigits#1{\ifx\relax#1\else%
% Unicode block for Arabic numerals starts at U+0660
% the following special command inserts the XML entity
% for the number, which will be converted to Unicode char
% by tex4ht
\special{t4ht@+&{35}x066#1{59}}x%
\expandafter\loopoverdigits\fi}

\def\arabicdigits#1{\NoFonts\loopoverdigits#1\relax\EndNoFonts}
\ifdefined\xeuniuseblock
\xeuniuseblock{Greek}
\xeuniuseblock{Arabic}
\fi
\makeatletter
\ConfigureEnv{arab}{\@rltrue}{\@rlfalse}{}{}
\Configure{ref}{\Link}{\EndLink}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The last time I used tex4ht successfully without this error was on December 14. I think that after that was when I did a routine texlive update, which probably included tex4ht. (I just checked now, December 22, and it looks like I am still up to date with the latest tex4ht.)

How can I fix this?

## Update

I've played around a bit more with it and found that the error goes away with a minimal example, suggesting the problem lies somewhere in my configuration or the project I am working on at the moment.

But when I use Git to rewind to before my last successful ODT-compilation, the error does *not* go away, suggesting that some change to `tex4ht` code is part of the problem.

## Update 2

I have not yet managed to put together a MWE that reproduces the error. But I have noticed that the `import` package may have something to do with what is going on: the previously lines in the terminal output before the fatal error seem to suggest that filepaths are being incorrectly expanded:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Argument of \etb@tgl@blx@usenamea has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Paragraph ended before \etb@tgl@blx@usenamea was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Missing number, treated as zero.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Missing number, treated as zero.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 8    Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 26   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 27   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 28   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 29   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 30   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 31   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?    Emergency stop.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

Note that `..//sections/0-intro.tex` should of course be `../sections/0-intro.tex` with no double-slash.

In my main tex file, I call all of the actual content of the document with an `\import` command:

```tex
\import{..}{_outline}
```

`_outline.tex` has some title information and then `\input{sections-compiled-by-Makefile}`. My `Makefile` automatically makes this file from the sections files in a directory called `sections/`. The file `sections-compiled-by-Makefile.tex` in this case reads:

```tex
\input{sections/0-intro.tex}
\input{sections/1-TOC.tex}
\input{sections/2-Table-of-Signs.tex}
\input{sections/3-List-of-Authors.tex}
\input{sections/z1-Conclusion.tex}
\input{sections/z2-Acknowledgments.tex}
```

As far as I can tell, I am using `\import` and `\input` commands properly. It works to compile using `xelatex`. The problem comes with `make4ht`.

Did anything about how `make4ht` implements the `import` package change that could have added a spurious extra slash?

## Update 3

Well, now I've noticed that a few lines further up in the terminal output is a line about too many }'s:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 57   Missing number, treated as zero.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 57   Missing } inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 57   Extra \endgroup.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 57   Too many }'s.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Missing number, treated as zero.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Missing number, treated as zero.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Argument of \etb@tgl@blx@usenamea has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Paragraph ended before \etb@tgl@blx@usenamea was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Missing number, treated as zero.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ..//sections/0-intro.tex 67   Missing number, treated as zero.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 8    Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 26   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 27   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 28   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 29   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 30   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./_lists-M-front-matter-WORD 31   Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    ?    Emergency stop.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

The line in question (line 57 of `sections/0-intro.tex`) is the first `\cite` command to appear in the document. So this leads me back to my earlier hypothesis that it has something to do with `biber` and/or my `.bib` file. (My hypothesis about `import` seems falsified by the fact that make4ht seems to think at least that it is successfully reading `sections/0-intro.tex`.)

To test it, I reverted my `.bib` file to how it was before December 14 (when I last successfully compiled the whole thing including citations). No luck -- it still gives the same fatal error.

Did `make4ht` recently change how it deals with `\cite` commands or `biber`, by any chance?

## Update 4

Now using the correct `-a debug` option, my full document's `make4ht` run provides some details on the `\cite` issue I mentioned in my "Update 3":

```
LaTeX Warning: First page is already shipped out, ignoring
               \AtBeginDvi on input line 66.

) (../_outline.tex [1]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   }
l.12 \maketitle

? ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                   }
l.12 \maketitle

? (..//sections-compiled-by-Makefile.tex (..//sections/0-intro.tex
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \begingroup
l.36 \cite[83]{roberts:marcianus:framing}.}

? ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   \begingroup
l.36 \cite[83]{roberts:marcianus:framing}.}

? ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \begingroup
l.36 \cite[83]{roberts:marcianus:framing}.}

? ! Argument of \etb@tgl@blx@useauthor has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.36 \cite[83]{roberts:marcianus:framing}.}

? Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \etb@tgl@blx@useauthor was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.36 \cite[83]{roberts:marcianus:framing}.}

? ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \scan_stop:
l.36 \cite[83]{roberts:marcianus:framing}.}

?
```

## Update 5: MWE

I've finally managed to isolate the problem. The package `xifthen` seems to trip up `biblatex` so that it no longer works.

main.tex:

```tex
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% Normal:
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oldfontcommands,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{import}

\usepackage[notes,
        alldates=       long,
        backend=        biber,
        bibwarn=        false,
        cmsdate=        both, % reprints: print `origdate` as well as `year`
        compresspages=  true,
        doi=            false,
        eprint=         false,
        giveninits=     true,   % abbreviate author first name(s)
        ibidtracker=    true,
        inheritshorthand,       % feature added for me by D.Fussner
        isbn=           false,
        mincrossrefs =  2,
        numbermonth =   false, % don't print journal issue month even if supplied, when an issue number is also supplied
        useibid,
        shorthandibid,
        strict=         true,
        url=            true,
        usetranslator=  true,
        uniquename= init
    ]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
    

\usepackage{xifthen}% provides \isempty test


\begin{document}

\cite[83]{roberts:marcianus:framing}

\end{document}
```

test.bib:

```
@article{roberts:marcianus:framing,
    author = {Roberts, Alexandre M.},
    journal = {Dumbarton Oaks Papers},
    pages = {69--102},
    read = {1},
    shorttitle = {Framing},
    title = {Framing a Middle Byzantine Alchemical Codex},
    volume = {73},
    year = {2019}
}
```

myconfig.cfg:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,ooffice}
\ConfigureOO{Footnote}{
<style:style
    style:name="Footnote"
    style:family="paragraph"
    style:parent-style-name="Standard"
    style:class="extra">\Hnewline
  <style:paragraph-properties
             fo:margin-left="0in"
             fo:margin-right="0in"
             fo:text-indent="0.1in"
              style:auto-text-indent="false"/>
  <style:text-properties fo:font-size="83.3333333333333333333333\%"
      style:font-size-asian="83.3333333333333333333333\%"
      style:font-size-complex="83.3333333333333333333333\%" />
</style:style>\Hnewline
<text:notes-configuration text:note-class="footnote"
    text:citation-style-name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
    text:citation-body-style-name="Footnote_20_anchor"
    style:num-format="1" text:start-value="0"
    text:footnotes-position="page"
    text:start-numbering-at="document" />\Hnewline
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_Symbol"
style:display-name="Footnote Symbol" style:family="text" >\Hnewline
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>
<style:style style:name="Footnote_20_anchor"
style:display-name="Footnote anchor" style:family="text">
  <style:text-properties style:text-position="super 58\%" />\Hnewline
</style:style>\Hnewline
}

\ConfigureOO{verse}{\Hnewline
<style:style style:name="verse"
             style:family="paragraph"
             style:parent-style-name="Text-body"
             style:next-style-name="Text-body">
<style:paragraph-properties  fo:margin-left="1.499cm"
             fo:margin-right="1cm"
             fo:margin-top="0cm"
             fo:margin-bottom="0cm"
             fo:text-indent="-0.499cm"
             style:auto-text-indent="false">
   <style:tab-stops/>
</style:paragraph-properties >
</style:style>
\Hnewline}

\def\loopoverdigits#1{\ifx\relax#1\else%
% Unicode block for Arabic numerals starts at U+0660
% the following special command inserts the XML entity
% for the number, which will be converted to Unicode char
% by tex4ht
\special{t4ht@+&{35}x066#1{59}}x%
\expandafter\loopoverdigits\fi}

\def\arabicdigits#1{\NoFonts\loopoverdigits#1\relax\EndNoFonts}
\ifdefined\xeuniuseblock
\xeuniuseblock{Greek}
\xeuniuseblock{Arabic}
\fi
\makeatletter
\ConfigureEnv{arab}{\@rltrue}{\@rlfalse}{}{}
\Configure{ref}{\Link}{\EndLink}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

When I run the command `make4ht -ux -a debug -f odt -c myconfig.cfg main.tex`, the following error shows up in the output:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/expl3-hooks.4ht)))
(./main.bbl))
! Argument of \etb@tgl@blx@useauthor has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.37 \cite[83]{roberts:marcianus:framing}
```

When I comment out `\usepackage{xifthen}` in `main.tex`, the compilation works as expected.

In case the rest of the debug output is useful, here it is:

```
[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir:
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: xelatex --no-pdf
[INFO]    mkparams: Latex options: -jobname=main
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht.sty: myconfig.cfg,,charset=utf-8
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht:  -cmozhtf -utf8 -.xdv
[INFO]    mkparams: build_file: main.mk4
[INFO]    mkparams: Output format: odt
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: main.tex
[INFO]    mkutils: Cannot open config file  main.mk4
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param correct_exit
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: setting param ext
[INFO]    make4ht-lib: Adding:  ext xdv
[INFO]    htlatex: LaTeX call: xelatex --no-pdf --interaction=errorstopmode -jobname=main   '\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\AddToHook{class/before}{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode myconfig.cfg,,charset=utf-8,ooffice.a.b.c.\input "\detokenize{main.tex}"'
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22> (./main.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tuenc-xetex-input.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2021/06/16 v3.7p configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/usepackage.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem12.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/delarray.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/before/framed' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/framed/before' instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty)

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/before/float' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/float/before' instead.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/biblatex-chicago-hooks.4
ht (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/biblatex-chicago
.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/biblatex-hooks.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.bb
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cb
x) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))

Package biblatex Warning: Since you are using the 'memoir' class,
(biblatex)                I'm leaving the formatting of the foot- and/or
(biblatex)                end-note mark and text to you..

) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xifthen/xifthen.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)) (./myconfig.cfg
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.4ht
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
l.855 --- TeX4ht warning --- nonprimitive \everypar ---
--- needs --- tex4ht main ---
(./main.tmp) (./main.xref)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/latex.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kastrup/binhex.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tuenc-xetex.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/fontmath.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht [1] [2]
[3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18]
[19] [20] [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26] [27] [28] [29] [30] [31] [32] [33]
[34] [35] [36] [37] [38] [39] [40] [41] [42] [43] [44] [45] [46] [47] [48]
[49] [50] [51] [52] [53])
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/memoir.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/book.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/verse.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/booktabs.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/array.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/dcolumn.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tabularx.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ifthen.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/biblatex-chicago.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/nameref.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/biblatex.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/url.4ht
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathml.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice-mml.4ht))

Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.
(biblatex)                Footnote detection will not work.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)) (./main.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/cms-american.lbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/expl3-hooks.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/expl3-hooks.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/expl3-hooks.4ht)))
(./main.bbl))
! Argument of \etb@tgl@blx@useauthor has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.37 \cite[83]{roberts:marcianus:framing}
```

Comment: Could you please add a mwe LaTeX example, and output od make4ht with the '-e debug' option?

Comment: Yes, I will do so. I added one just now before realizing that I had made a stupid mistake. Once I manage to reproduce the error with a minimal example, I will post it.

Comment: I have struggled to reproduce it on a minimal example. But I did notice that without biber, which stopped working as it does from time to time, the compilation works. When I reset biber (with `rm -rf \`biber --cache\``), the fatal error reappeared. So maybe it has something to do with my .bib file.

Comment: I'm still having trouble isolating the problem, but I've made some updates in the hopes that perhaps they will somehow help.

Comment: By the way, am I using the `-e debug` option wrong? My command is `make4ht -ux -e debug -f odt -c $configfile $filename.out.tex`. Somehow whenever I add that option, biber fails to run, and so the compile works, just without formatted citations. Sorry to be so confused.

Comment: sorry, it was `-a debug`. I was on mobile when I suggested it and got it wrong

Comment: we recently fixed lot of things related to BibLaTeX and Hyperref, so it is quite possible that it caused some issues for you.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful to know. Based on that, I have managed to isolate the problem, as described in "Update 5" above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the error happens because of redefinition of the `\TE@repl` command in the Xifthen package. The problem is that it clashes with TeX4ht's patch for `\ifthenelse`, which redefines `\begingroup` to insert some code and then redefines it back to it's original meaning. We can use the saved original version of `\begingroup`, `\sv:begingroup`, instead.

Try this patch file, `xifthen.4ht`:

```
\def \TE@repl #1#2{%
  \long \def \@tempc ##1#1##2{%
    \def \@tempb{\@tempc}%
    \sv:begingroup % Thanks MPG
      \toks@ {##2}%
      \edef \@tempa {\the \toks@}% <- UF v1.3
    \expandafter \endgroup
    \ifx \@tempa \@tempb
      \toks@ \expandafter {\the \toks@ ##1}%
      \expandafter \@gobble
    \else
      \toks@ \expandafter {\the \toks@ ##1#2}%
      \expandafter \@tempc
    \fi
    ##2%
  }%
  \toks@ \expandafter {\expandafter}%
  \expandafter \@tempc \the \toks@ #1\@tempc
}
\Hinput{xifthen}
\endinput
```

It then compiles without errors:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm afraid I'm too ignorant to know how to use that patch file, but I look forward to trying it out once it updates on texlive.

Comment: @AlexRoberts you can put it to the same directory as your TeX file is. TeX Live should get update soon.

Comment: The patch worked -- thanks again!